# VSCode for react application debugging (node version 8.1.2)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Today my VSCode got upgraded to `1.2.0`, since then VSC debugger is failing. So based on the documentation we added a `"protocol": "inspector"`. But now we are getting another error saying `Ensure Node was launched with --inspect. Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms`

My current `launch.json` looks like

```
launch.json
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "port": 9229
  },
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test"
  }
]
 }



VSCode Version: Version 1.20.0 (1.20.0)
Node Version: 8.1.2
```

Any pointers for fixing this issue would be great help

Thanks,
San

Comment: Did you launch node with --inspect?

Comment: No, I wasn't doing anything special with my previous version.

Comment: The error message implies that you're running the attach config, maybe you meant to run the launch config.